# Setting AutoScrollPosition when AutoScroll is set to false

Tags: c#, scroll

I have created a custom scrollbar and I would like to move my scrollable and zoomable panel to the position of the thumb in scrollbar. As I don't want to make Default Scrollbar visible I have set AutoScroll to false.

To scroll in the panel, I am using property of AutoScrollPosition as

```
Panel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point( x, y );
```

I am able to scroll the panel to some location. However, the value of AutoScrollPosition is not going beyond some arbitrary value, in my case its -181 and therefore does not move beyond that. I have spent lots of time in this bug. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some more of your code or an example of what you have described (i.e. an image) so that we may more easily help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. If someone has similar problem it can be fixed as

```
Panel.SetBounds( 0, -ScrollBar.Value, Panel.Width, Panel.Height );
```

where the "ScrollBar.Value" is the value from vertical scrollbar thumb position.